# what is this configuration error with Vue.js eslint

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I am newer on vueJs. I try this basic code in my vue to modify datas of a component in a vue:

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <h1> {{ message }}
            <h2> Hello {{ firstname }} {{ lastname }} de {{ from }} ! </h2>
            <label> Firstname : <input type="text" v-model="person.firstname" /> </label>
            <label> Lastname : <input type="text" v-model="person.lastname" /> </label>
            <label> Message : <input type="text" v-model="message" /> </label>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      data () {
          person: {
            firstname: 'John',
            lastname: 'Doe'
          },
          message: 'Welcome!'
      }
    }
    </script>
```

I get this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/Hello.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Hello.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\1900780\Documents\Afpa\Ressources\PHP\vueJs1\myproject\src\components\Hello.vue: Unexpected token, expected ";" (16:16)

  14 |       person: {
  15 |         firstname: 'John',
> 16 |         lastname: 'Doe'
     |                 ^
  17 |       },
  18 |       message: 'Welcome!'
  19 |   }
    at Object.raise (C:\Users\...\vueJs1\myproject\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:7013:17)
    at Object.unexpected (C:\Users\...\vueJs1\myproject\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8384:16)
    at Object.semicolon (C:\Users\...\vueJs1\myproject\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8366:40)
    at Object.parseExpressionStatement (C:\Users\...\vueJs1\myproject\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11193:10)
    at Object.parseStatementContent (C:\Users\...\vueJs1\myproject\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10792:19)
    at Object.parseStatement (C:\Users\...\vueJs1\myproject\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10658:17)
    at Object.parseLabeledStatement (C:\Users\...\vueJs1\myproject\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11185:22)
    at Object.parseStatementContent (C:\Users\...\vueJs1\myproject\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10790:19)
    at Object.parseStatement (C:\Users\...\vueJs1\myproject\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10658:17)
    at Object.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (C:\Users\...\vueJs1\myproject\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11234:25)
    at Object.parseBlockBody (C:\Users\...\vueJs1\myproject\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11221:10)
    at Object.parseBlock (C:\Users\...\vueJs1\myproject\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11205:10)
    at Object.parseStatementContent (C:\Users\...\vueJs1\myproject\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10734:21)
    at Object.parseStatement (C:\Users\...\vueJs1\myproject\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10658:17)
    at Object.parseLabeledStatement (C:\Users\...\vueJs1\myproject\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11185:22)
    at Object.parseStatementContent (C:\Users\...\vueJs1\myproject\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10790:19)
```

I use @vue/cli 4.1.2 and webpack.
My package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "myproject",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "core-js": "^3.4.4",
        "vue": "^2.6.10"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.1.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
        "eslint": "^5.16.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
          "node": true
        },
        "extends": [
          "plugin:vue/essential",
          "eslint:recommended"
        ],
        "rules": {},
        "parserOptions": {
          "parser": "babel-eslint",
          "ecmaVersion": 6
        }
      },
      "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions"
      ]
    }
```

My code seems to be correct. I don't understand this error. Is there a config to do with babel parser and where is the config file ?
I added an eccmaversion in the package.json file configuration, but it does not seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably you mean: `data() {
    return {
      person: {
        firstname: "John",
        lastname: "Doe"
      },
      message: "Welcome!"
    }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Houps! i just forgot the return statement:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      person: {
        firstname: 'John',
        lastname: 'Doe'
      },
      message: 'Welcome!'
    }
  }
}
```